# Ajax Rating control in DetailsView ReadOnly Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a weird issue on my web page with AjaxControlToolkit Rating control.

The following is a TemplateField in a DetailsView:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="RatingUP" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"><ContentTemplate>
      <ajaxToolkit:Rating runat="server" ID="RRating" AutoPostback="True" OnChanged="RRating_Changed" CurrentRating="1"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="RatingUP2" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"><ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:Rating runat="server" ID="RRating2" AutoPostback="True"  OnChanged="RRating_Changed" CurrentRating="1"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
  </UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Everything is fine in Edit Mode, but in ReadOnly mode I get the following error:

> The TargetControlID of 'RRating2_RatingExtender' is not valid. A
>   control with ID 'RRating2' could not be found.

What could be the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: where is the part of the code that work with `RRating2_RatingExtender`?

Comment: There isn't any. That's the point! I don't know what the `RRating2_RatingExtender` is.

Comment: `Ctrl+F` don't have any result?

Comment: no :-| There are no RatingExtenders

Comment: I think the problem is in the DetailsView. It implements [INamingContainer interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx), so all repeating elements get renamed, and TargetControlID does not match. I can't provide any workaround here, but I just say AjaxControlToolkit is not designed to be used inside INamingContainers, such as Repeaters, DetailsView etc.